# Почему при сборке ядра cross-gcc странно себя ведёт?

Tags: c, ассемблер, kernel, кросс-компиляция, osdev

я учусь писать систему, использую кросс-компилятор gcc. Как всегда, появилась одна большая проблема: если я в файле *kernel.c* создам маску символа(моя ос работает в защищённом режиме, изначально был сменён режим на графический(VGA)) в главной функции (main):

```
#include "../libc/vga.h"
#include "../libc/chars.h"

void main()
{
    int8 NULL[64] = {
        0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,
        0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,
        0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,
        0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,
        0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,
        0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,
        0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,
        0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0
    };
    redraw(0x00);
    print_mask(NULL, 8, 8, 0x34);
}
```

то символ выводится на экран без проблем, однако, если я вынесу определение маски символа '0' в любое место:

```
#include "../libc/vga.h"
#include "../libc/chars.h"

int8 NULL[64] = {
        0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,
        0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,
        0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,
        0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,
        0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,
        0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,
        0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,
        0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0
    };

void main()
{
    redraw(0x00);
    print_mask(NULL, 8, 8, 0x34);
}
```

то ничего не выводится, в чём проблема? Такое происходит со всеми массивами.

Comment: `NULL` - удачный, однако, выбор имени для переменной

Comment: Согласен, но, даже при использовании другого названия переменной это не решает мою проблему.

Comment: если это компиляция кросс-компилятором и под свою ОСь, то може там и скрипт для линковщика отдельный?

Comment: Да, причём не совсем правильный, но я не знаю, как его корректно написать

Comment: `ENTRY(_start)
SECTIONS
{
    . = 32K;
    .text BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
    {
        *(.text*)
    }
    .rodata BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
    {
        *(.rodata*)
    }
    .data BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
    {
        *(.data*)
    }
    .bss BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
    {
        *(COMMON)
        *(.bss*)
    }
}
`

Comment: Так же я достаю бинарник с помощью `objcopy`

Comment: я думаю, что во втором случае, NULL не попадает в результирующий бинарник.

Comment: А как сделать, чтобы попадал?